# surface size iOS cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have agate on cocos2d v1.0.1. I'm getting black screen on iOS 8.1.
When I'm testing it with iOS 7.1 or 8 it works great and surface size on debug area is 640 X 1136 for iPhone 5, but with 8.1 - screen is black and surface size is 1280 X 2272. 
I tried 2 methods to determine screen size: `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size` and `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize]`
Thanks

Comment: Update cocos2d to v3.x, your version is far, far too old. It's not just the screen display but Apple now requires users to submit armv7s (64-bit) code in their apps which cocos2d v2.x has severe issues with (but at least compiles) and I can only imagine v1.x will be even worse than that (probably doesn't even compile to 64 bit without applying fixes).

Comment: Thank you. Updating to new version resolve a problem